# How to show values in suggestion instead of label jquery autocomplete and search should be process on the basic of label field

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, search-suggestion

[Here is the image of current working operation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DyUK.png) I am using jquery auto complete . But my problem is when i type item1 it shows item1 as suggestion. And i want to show when i type item1 is should be show zzz1 inside suggestion box. 
My code is here.

```
<input name="jobCat" id="jobCat" value="" type="text" placeholder="Search category by keyword"/>
<script>
$(function() {
var datasource = [
{ "label": "item1", "value": "zzz1", "id": 1 },
{ "label": "item2", "value": "zzz2", "id": 2 },
{ "label": "item3", "value": "zzz3", "id": 3 }];
$("#jobCat").autocomplete({
        source: datasource,
        select: function (event, ui) { }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit, I found something usefull in the [documentation](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data)... For having the values in the suggestions, instead of the labels.

```js
var datasource = [
  { "label": "item1", "value": "zzz1", "id": 1 },
  { "label": "item2", "value": "zzz2", "id": 2 },
  { "label": "item3", "value": "zzz3", "id": 3 }];
  
$("#jobCat").autocomplete({
  source: datasource,
}).autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
    return $( "<li>" )
      .append( "<div>" + item.value + " - ID: " + item.id + "</div>" )
      .appendTo( ul );
  };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input name="jobCat" id="jobCat" value="" type="text" placeholder="Search category by keyword"/>
```

Comment: ok working fine,, may be there is some issue on my side. One more thing bro,, if i want to limit the number of results to 5 then ??